# If the column space of $A$ = the nul sapce of $A$, show that Nul $A^2=\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ Be an $n$ x $n$ matrix.

If the column space of $A$ = the nul space of $A$, show that Nul $A^2=\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just using the definitions.

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. By definition, $Ax\in col(A)$. So $Ax\in\ker(A)$. Thus $A(Ax)=A^2x=0$. This proves that $x\in\ker(A^2)$.